# Paperclip: Name of the event that gets triggered after file creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to delete some animated GIFs in Paperclip after they're converted to MP4 -- but what is the name of the event that gets triggered after the files are created in the file system?

Tested [dgilperez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28781897/184184): the `after_post_process` event is triggered before the file is created on the file system.

```
def on_after_post_process
      puts(self.attachment.path)
end
```

Prints:

```
 => "/home/user/rails-repo/public/system/photos/attachments//original/file.gif"
```

But actually the file was created at:

```
 => "/home/user/rails-repo/public/system/photos/attachments/000/000/<id>/original/file.gif"
```

Also tried `after_create` event of ActiveRecord. In that event, the file path is correct but the file was not created yet.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#events), you can use `after_post_process` callback or the more specific `after_<attachment>_post_process`.

Comment: By the way man, any chance you're up for hire for a short gig?

Comment: @MarkBoulder ping me at twitter.com/dgilperez

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip saves the attachments to disk in an `after_save` callback. `after_save` happens after `after_create`, so you can't use `after_create`. You can create your own `after_save` and have it only run for new records:

```
  after_save :process_file
  def process_file
    # Don't do anything on update. new_record? is always true here.
    return if !id_changed?
    # XXX Do your business here
  end
```